No ISCSI bandwidth bump using multipath
Summary: I setup 2 IP networks between a set of machines, each routed over a set of physical Ethernet links that does not overlap one-another (using one does not impede the performance of the other). I export iSCSI devices over these networks and use multipath on the client side to take advantage of the combined bandwidth of both networks but its does not seem to produce the performance expected. See below for details.
I set up three machines as high-availability storage. I use two 10Gb Ethernet interfaces on each machine to create a fully connected network between the three of them and without using any switch. The physical topology, including interface names, resemble the one shown below:
    |-------------|        |-------------|    
    |             |        |             |    
|----eno4  A  eno5----------eno4  C  eno5----|
|   |             |        |             |   |
|   |-------------|        |-------------|   |
|                                            |
|--------------------------------|           |
                                 |           |
               |-------------|   |           |
               |             |   |           |
           |----eno4  B  eno5----|           |
           |   |             |               |
           |   |-------------|               |
           |                                 |
           |---------------------------------|

In all machines A, B and C, vlan interfaces are derived from eno4 and eno5 with a vlan id set to 6. vlan interfaces are set as members of a Linux bridge br, which is configured as follows:
/etc/network/interface:
auto br
iface br inet manual
        address 192.168.0.1/32
        address 192.168.1.1/32
        bridge-ports eno4.6 eno5.6
        hwaddress aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
        post-up ip link set dev br mtu 9710
        post-up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eno4.autoconf=0
        post-up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eno5.autoconf=0
        post-up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eno4/6.autoconf=0
        post-up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eno5/6.autoconf=0
        post-up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.br.autoconf=0
        post-up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.br.autoconf=0
        post-up sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0
        post-up ip link set dev br arp off 
        post-up arp -i br -s 192.168.0.2 ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa #ac:1f:6c:6f:e8:e0
        post-up arp -i br -s 192.168.1.2 ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa
        post-up arp -i br -s 192.168.0.3 aa:ff:bb:ee:cc:dd #ac:1f:6c:6f:ea:10
        post-up arp -i br -s 192.168.1.3 aa:ff:bb:ee:cc:dd
        post-up bridge fdb add ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa dev eno4.6 master static
        post-up bridge fdb add aa:ff:bb:ee:cc:dd dev eno5.6 master static
        post-up bridge link set dev eno4.6 flood off learning off 
        post-up bridge link set dev eno5.6 flood off learning off 
        post-up sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eno4/6.send_redirects=0
        post-up sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eno5/6.send_redirects=0
        post-up sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.br.send_redirects=0
        post-up sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
        post-up ip route add 192.168.0.2 dev br
        post-up ip route add 192.168.0.3 dev br
        post-up ip route add 192.168.1.2 via 192.168.0.3 dev br
        post-up ip route add 192.168.1.2 via 192.168.0.2 dev br
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

To sum up, IPv6 autoconfiguration is deactivated, the bridge is set to not flood the network and not learn from incoming frames. Also, STP and ARP are deactivated. Instead, "routing/switching" tables needed by the bridge and the IP protocol are manually set when the bridge is setup and no broadcast is necessary to use the network, which would result in a L2 storm. This allows setting up two IPs networks: one (192.168.0.0) sends packets directly from a host to another using a single Ethernet link, the second (192.168.1.0) send packets indirectly from a host to another, i.e., via the third host. This means that not only if 1 Ethernet link is down, any pair of hosts can still contact another (High Availability) but also if all links are working, there are two 10Gb links between any pair of hosts (Aggregation). For the indirect IP network to work, all nodes also need the nft rules below:
/etc/nftables.conf:
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter;
        }
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter;
        }
        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority filter;
        }
}

table ip iptable {
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority -300; policy accept;
                iif != br drop
        }

        chain prerouting {
                type filter hook prerouting priority -300; policy accept;
                ip daddr 192.168.1.2 ip daddr set 192.168.0.2 ip saddr set 192.168.1.3 accept
                ip daddr 192.168.1.3 ip daddr set 192.168.0.3 ip saddr set 192.168.1.2 accept
        }
}

I did confirm that is any of the Ethernet link is removed (e.g., by deactivating eno4 or eno5 in one of the machines), then all machines can still ping all other, either via the direct or the indirect network.
If you have any simpler (and as cost effective) way to achieve this, please do shortly suggest; I initially though about some kind of LACP but I quickly realized that would not be possible in my context and this is out of the scope of my question. I might also have instability issues, where some interface randomly deactivate itself, although this does not seem to happen anymore. If you have any insight, please share although again, this is not the main focus of the question.
Now I use both direct (192.168.0.0) and indirect (192.168.1.0) IP networks to export block devices using targetcli. Here is a dump of machine A's export:
root@A:~# targetcli ls /
o- / ......................................................................................... [...]
  o- backstores .............................................................................. [...]
  | o- block .................................................................. [Storage Objects: 1]
  | | o- lun-A-1 ............................ [/dev/mapper/blockdev1 (16.0GiB) write-thru activated]
  | |   o- alua ................................................................... [ALUA Groups: 1]
  | |     o- default_tg_pt_gp ....................................... [ALUA state: Active/optimized]
  | o- fileio ................................................................. [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- pscsi .................................................................. [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- ramdisk ................................................................ [Storage Objects: 0]
  o- iscsi ............................................................................ [Targets: 1]
  | o- iqn.2024-05.com.mydom.hosts.A:data1 ............................................... [TPGs: 1]
  |   o- tpg1 .................................................................. [gen-acls, no-auth]
  |     o- acls .......................................................................... [ACLs: 0]
  |     o- luns .......................................................................... [LUNs: 1]
  |     | o- lun1 ....................... [block/lun-A-1 (/dev/mapper/blockdev1) (default_tg_pt_gp)]
  |     o- portals .................................................................... [Portals: 2]
  |       o- 192.168.0.1:3274 ................................................................. [OK]
  |       o- 192.168.1.1:3274 ................................................................. [OK]
  o- loopback ......................................................................... [Targets: 0]
  o- vhost ............................................................................ [Targets: 0]
  o- xen-pvscsi ....................................................................... [Targets: 0]
root@A:~#

Machine B and C can import blockdev1; for example, here is machine C's iscsi session:
root@C:~# iscsiadm -m session
tcp: [7] 192.168.0.1:3274,1 iqn.2024-05.com.mydom.hosts.a:data1 (non-flash)
tcp: [9] 192.168.1.1:3274,1 iqn.2024-05.com.mydom.hosts.a:data1 (non-flash)
root@C:~# 

Which, in turns, allows for multipath setup on machine C:
/etc/multipath.conf
root@chamaeleon:~# cat /etc/multipath.conf 
defaults {
        verbosity 2
        path_selector "service-time 0"
        path_grouping_policy multibus
        uid_attribute ID_SERIAL
        failback immediate
        no_path_retry fail
        user_friendly_names yes
}

blacklist {
        wwid .*
}

blacklist_exceptions {
        wwid "001122334455667788990011223344556"
}

multipaths {
        multipath {
                wwid "001122334455667788990011223344556"
                alias A-14
                path_grouping_policy    multibus
                path_selector           "service-time 0"
        }
}
root@chamaeleon:~# 

and, to check that multipath does work as expected:
root@C:~# multipath -ll
A-1 (001122334455667788990011223344556) dm-50 LIO-ORG,lun-A-1
size=16G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=50 status=active
  |- 7:0:0:14 sdb 8:16 active ready running
  `- 8:0:0:14 sdc 8:32 active ready running
root@C:~# ls -l /dev/mapper/eridanus-14 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 May 28 15:31 /dev/mapper/A-1 -> ../dm-50
root@C:~#

Function and performance test:
root@C:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/A-1 bs=64M status=progress
16911433728 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 32 s, 528 MB/s 
dd: error writing '/dev/mapper/A-1': No space left on device
256+0 records in
255+0 records out
17163091968 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 51.8441 s, 331 MB/s
root@C:~#

(where there has been a 30-ish seconds stall after showing No space left on device and before the rest of the output).
Now, if I deactivate the iscsi export via the indirect network:
root@C:~# multipath -ll
A-1 (001122334455667788990011223344556) dm-50 LIO-ORG,lun-A-1
size=16G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=50 status=active
  `- 7:0:0:14 sdb 8:16 active ready running
root@C:~# 

and run another performance test:
root@C:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/A-1 bs=64M status=progress
17045651456 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 30 s, 568 MB/s 
dd: error writing '/dev/mapper/A-1': No space left on device
256+0 records in
255+0 records out
17163091968 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 53.7414 s, 319 MB/s
root@C:~# 

It shows that running on a single link does not degrade the performance. If anything, the performance actually improves.
Now if I try to deactivate the iscsi export on the direct network and activate back the same export on the indirect network:
root@C:~# multipath -ll
A-1 (001122334455667788990011223344556) dm-50 LIO-ORG,lun-A-1
size=16G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=50 status=active
  `- 8:0:0:14 sdc 8:32 active ready running
root@C:~#

and run yet another performance test:
root@C:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/A-1 bs=64M status=progress
16575889408 bytes (17 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 30 s, 552 MB/s 
dd: error writing '/dev/mapper/A-1': No space left on device
256+0 records in
255+0 records out
17163091968 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 57.3237 s, 299 MB/s
root@C:~# 

Then I see that even with a single link on the indirect network, the performance is the same. No much, if any, of a performance drop to deplore.
As a final performance test, in order to know how far the performance of the iscsi setup described above is from the best possible performance, I run dd directly on the nvme device from the host that holds it:
root@A:~# !dd
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/blockdev1 bs=64M status=progress
16911433728 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 18 s, 937 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/mapper/blockdev1': No space left on device
256+0 records in
255+0 records out
17163091968 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 18.6119 s, 922 MB/s
root@A:~# 

And this latter test suggest there is still room for a x2 iscsi performance, more or less, minus the unavoidable (unknown) overhead.
The tests above seem to suggest that the multipath setup is unable to take advantage of the double link available. I tried to override the vendor path_grouping_policy to multibus
and path_selector "service-time 0" (default for LIO-ORG is path_grouping_policy set to "group_by_prio", but it does not seem to improve the situation. I am unsure about the policy and grouping settings that would allow multipath to take advantage and the bandwidth of both links at the same time. If you have any information beyond its manpage, that would be very helpful.
